# How can I influence what Google shows under the rich result "Latest from [example.com]"?

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, search-results, rich-snippets

For the website that I am working on, Google has been displaying for a while a rich result consisting of three cards under the title "Latest from [name of the website]".

The problem with these results is that it is taking the latest post from the entire website. We need it to display the results belonging only to one branch/directory of the website, such as blog articles and not other types of posts (we have classified ads appearing in those results).

After searching the internet up and down, I have not managed to find what structured data, if any, corresponds to these "Latest from [...]" rich results. They started appearing as soon as we began adding Schema.org structured data to our website such as `Organization` and `SiteNavigationElement`, but I have not figured out if there is any connection between them.

The results we see are both on desktop and on mobile.

Here are a couple of examples:

thepeninsulaqatar.com:

[image: screenshot]

css-tricks.com:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: is your site a Google News Publisher?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. We have not yet received the approval from Google to be included in Google News. Therefore the "Latest from [...]" rich result, though very similar, it isn the "Top Stories" one that appears for websites which are Google News Publishers.

Comment: I also can't find any documentation about this feature on Google SERP. My guess is that it is reading RSS feeds. I'm not sure what it uses for the images.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add the news article https://schema.org/NewsArticle schema on each of your articles (it will help google understand especialy the "Date" part of the news.
Also you'll have to help google understand those are the last news article on the homepage with some Hn specification.

The current Hn use on your homepage doesn't reflect it. It's a bit hard to understand for google your structuration. You may need on your home page to have something like this

```
<h1>The peninsula qatar</h1>
    <h2>Latest news From qatar</h2>
        <h3>Amir to carryout Eid Al Fitr prayers tomorrow</h3>
        <h3>Qatar celebrates International Nurses Day</h3>
        <h3>MoI to intensify foot patrols during Eid holidays</h3>
        <h3>Preventive measures for Eid prayer</h3>
        <h3>Four deaths, 343 cases in Qatar on May 11</h3>
```

Comment: Thanks, Patrick, this is helpful for me.